# query for get result of two tables that are not relate with each other

Tags: laravel

i have three tables and models A B C. A relate with B and B relate with c but A and C are not relate with each other now i want data from c for A through B what is the query for it.?

Comment: What are the relationships between these modes i.e. how does A relate to B and how does B relate to C? Can you add your models to your question?

Comment: you are right. but how can i edit my question?

Comment: On the left underneath your question and above the comments  you should see a link called "edit".

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

(AModel : A table model)

```
App\AModel::join('b', function($join) {
    return $join->on('a.id', 'b.a_id');
})
->join('c', function($join) {
    return $join->on('b.id', 'c.b_id');
})
->where();
```

Write your condition in where.

Comment: @Adil The reason I imagine your question was downvotes is because you haven't provided a great deal of information. It would have helped if you had added the columns for your tables, how they relate and anything you've tried so far. Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask